Multilevel Model Residuals Scatterplot Assumptions
I am conducting multilevel modelling (MLM) in SPSS (mixed modeling) to analyze cross-sectional repeated measures data.  One of my dependent variables is a survey question scaled 1 to 10, which produced the attached scatterplot of the residuals, which is angled downward but still balanced around the zero line.  Could this "angling" cause any concern for interpreting that the MLM assumptions are being met?


You only have a fixed number of outcomes, so the pattern you are observing reflects that.
In fact, you can quite closely reproduce this pattern by plotting residuals of a binomial process:

...or the Pearson residuals of a multilevel model:

What to make of this?
What you're really observing is that:

If your model assumes a normally distributed error term, this assumption is not reasonable, and you should use a GLMM instead.
For models that do allow discrete probability distributions, a simple residuals vs fitted plot is not very informative.
For multilevel models, you have to think about what assumptions are actually being made, and how you might go about diagnosing those.
If you are willing to use R, all of these considerations can be taken into account using the amazing package DHARMa.


Simulated data to reproduce the figures:
# Binomial example
set.seed(2024)
n    <- 1000
size <- 10
x    <- rnorm(n, 10, 3)
ID   <- factor(rep(1:100, each = 10))
Z    <- model.matrix(~ 0 + ID)
eta  <- -1.8 + 0.2 * x + Z %*% rnorm(ncol(Z))
y    <- rbinom(n, size, binomial()$linkinv(eta)) + 1
DF   <- data.frame(x, y)
rm(n, size, x, eta, y)
LM <- lm(y ~ x, DF)

plot(LM, which = 1, pch = 21, bg = "steelblue1", xlim = c(2, 10))

# Binomial multilevel example
set.seed(2024)
n    <- 1000
size <- 10
x    <- rnorm(n, 6, 3)
ID   <- factor(rep(1:100, each = 10))
Z    <- model.matrix(~ 0 + ID)
eta  <- -0.75 + 0.15 * x + Z %*% rnorm(ncol(Z), 0, 0.5)
y    <- rbinom(n, size, binomial()$linkinv(eta)) + 1
DF   <- data.frame(x, y, ID)
rm(n, size, x, eta, y)

LM <- lm(y ~ x, DF)

require("lme4")
LMM <- lmer(y ~ x + (1 | ID), DF)

plot(residuals(LMM) ~ fitted(LMM), pch = 21, bg = "steelblue1", xlim = c(2, 10),
     cex = 0.7)
mtext("Pearson Residuals vs Fitted", 3, 0.5)


Thank you so much for your help.  I am using a Linear Mixed Model (LMM) in SPSS (MIXED command), and don't know much about R.  I am attempting to assess the multilevel/mixed model assumptions of Linearity, Normality and Homoskedasticity through assessment of the Level-1 (and also Level-2) residuals in scatterplots (as well as Histograms and Q-Q Plots).  To clarify are you saying that this scatterplot does not satisfy these assumptions, and that a GLMM will be required?

Also, I have been exploring transformations (e.g. log, square root, etc) for my dependent variables.  Would these potentially allow the use of LMM instead of GLMM?

@MarkS. A transformation cannot change the discrete nature of the outcome. While you can approximate a binomial process with a normal distribution, this approximation is only good if the probability of success is close to $p = \frac{1}{2}$ and/or the number of trials is very large. Since you only have 10 possible outcomes, it is better to use a model made for discrete outcomes, like a binomial GLMM.

Thank you.  I am reviewing GLMM in SPSS now.  So for the Link function would you recommend Binomial Distribution and Identity Link function?

I also have some continuous DVs.  Would these benefit from GLMM using a linear model link function, or would I do just as well sticking with LMM?  Thank you for your continued help!

@MarkS. Follow-up questions are be better suited for a new post (comments can be deleted without notice). But in short: (1) The only purpose of the link function is to restrict the predictions to valid outcomes, I explain that here at the linked timestamp. If you don't want the S-shape imposed by the link function, you can transform the explanatory variable, or use a spline. (2) For continuous variables without strong skew, there is no immediate reason to use GLMM, but it is hard to judge without details.

Thank you for all your help today.  I will plan to use both GLMM and LMM depending on the type of response variable.

@MarkS. You're welcome! If this answers your question, you can click the check mark to accept it.
